# How to Insert image from local(Desktop) into google spreadsheet cell using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to Insert Images from the desktop(Local) in our Google Spreadsheet Cells using Script

Note: We can insert an image (from a computer) into the cell using: Insert -> Image -> Image in cell. And can I do the same using Apps Script?

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*This is not possible.*

#### More Information:

Google Apps Script is a server-side run script which does not normally have access to your local machine to any degree.

As [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) pointed out, however, you *can* upload a file from your local machine with an HTML dialog. There is a great example on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60828884/11551468), though the difference would be that you need to change the `doGet(e)` function for some function that you can access on button click to show a modal:

```
function myFunction() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'dialog');
}
```

The issue arises however with *inserting the image itself into a cell of a Google Sheet*. While you can easily save an selected image in this way to Google Drive, as of time of writing this answer, there is no way to insert an image into a cell from Apps Script, more information on this you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736463).

#### Feature Request:

There is an [active feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129384672) for this to be implemented on Google's Issue Tracker. If you are interested in having this implemented,then I urge you to follow this link and click the star in the top-left to indicate to Google that this is a feature of priority for their users.

Comment: Not really. You can use html dialog to get the image and send it as blob to server

Comment: @TheMaster you are right, thanks for pointing that out. It's still not possible, but for other reasons.